# How to train data with different feature size

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, normalization

My train data are different directed graphs, each has an evaluation value based on the graph structure and the values on nodes. My model should predicate the evaluation value for any new graph.

To describe the graph structure I use an adjacency matrix and reshape it to one row. For node values I normalize them to range [0,1] and append them to the end of the row, at the end this row will be one feature vector.

But the number of nodes and connections in directed graphs are different, so my feature vector will have different length. How should I handle this?

1. take the longest vector and fill 0 for other samples?
2. take a fix vector size and cut feature randomly if it exceed or ignore that sample?
3. use some technique to resize the long vector to a short one? What technique I can use?
4. any good algorithms for graph structure learning? or any ML algorithms works with dynamic feature size?

Thanks